# The difference between 'rating' and 'rated'

Tags: word-choice

> In order to improve your chess skill, you need to play it with the higher 'rating' **or** 'rated' players more often.

Which one is correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use either.

> A higher rat**ing** player

is the same as

> A player ***of*** higher rating

here, '*rating*' is a noun (and 'higher' is an *adjective*).

> A higher rat**ed** player

is the same as

> A player who is rated higher.

here, '*rated*' is an adjective (and 'higher' is an *adverb*).

Comment: I might be inclined to hyphenate the first one (a higher-rating player), but, even with the hyphen, I don't like it as much as the second one (a higher rated player). The way I'd probably write it, though is ***a more highly-rated player***.

Answer (score 2):

Your **rating** is your number score. You need to play higher-**rated** players to raise your **rating**. Beating a player with a higher **rating** will improve your score.  In the chess world you will much more often here how to "beat higher-**rated** players" not "beat higher **rating** players"

(source: native speaker and chess player!)

[How to beat higher-rated players- chess.com](http://www.chess.com/video/player/how-to-beat-higher-rated-players)

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please mark it as a correct answer.